# split comma separated JSON

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to implement a search functionaltiy for a restaurants, currently in my database the the field menu_type is a varchar, the values are separated by commas

`"Burger, Cafe, Italian, American,Irish"`

how can I make it so that when somebody searches for "Burger" it will show him all the results which have Burger only as menu_type OR "Burger" is a part of their menu_type

```
@app.route('/api/restaurants/search/',methods=['GET'])
def get_restaurant():
    menu = request.json.get('menu')
    restaurant = Restaurant.query.filter_by(menu_type=menu).all()
    return jsonify(json_list=[i.serialize for i in restaurant])
```

my restaurant model:

```
class Restaurant(db.Model):
    __tablename__ ='Restaurant'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    address1 =db.Column(db.String(128))
    address2 = db.Column(db.String(32))
    phone =db.Column(db.Integer)
    lat = db.Column(db.Float(precision='12,10'))
    lng = db.Column(db.Float(precision='12,10'))
    cost = db.Column(db.Integer)
    menu_type = db.Column(db.String(64))
    rate =db.Column(db.Float(precision='3,2'))
    offer=db.Column(db.String(128))

    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return {
           'id'  : self.id,
           'name': self.name,
           'address1'  : self.address1,
           'address2': self.address2,
           'phone'  : self.phone,
           'lat': self.lat,
           'lng'  : self.lng,
           'cost': self.cost,
           'menu_type'  : self.menu_type,
           'rate': self.rate,
           'offer' : self.offer
           }
```

Comment: To search for burger your SQL query will be SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE menu_type LIKE %Burger%; But you could normalize and make a table with menu_types and hold only a reference to it in your main table. Thenn the database will be able to use an index to search for the menu type (now it can't)

Comment: Hi! thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Like %searched_word%, % it's important because it's a substitute for any characters, but the database won't be able to fully use an index

Comment: Comma separated columns of related data typically means you need another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following for filtering:

`Restaurant = Restaurant.query.filter(Restaurant.menu_type.like('% {0}%').format(menu)).all()`

This will give you the result because you are doing a `like` query.